# Getting error while fetching certificate from windows certificate store in Golang using `certtostore`?

Tags: windows, go, x509certificate, glide-golang, golang-migrate

I want to use certificate bundle from windows certificate store, can anyone please tell me what wrong I am doing here?

My Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"

    "github.com/google/certtostore"
)

type certmgr struct {
    certToStore certtostore.CertStorage
}

func main() {
    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
        var cert certmgr
        certInStore, err := cert.certToStore.Cert()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("message", "Error in getting system store certificate ...")
        }

        fmt.Println("Windows System Store Certificate", *certInStore)

    }
}
```

The Error I am getting :

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x0 pc=0xbe2dda]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        C:/Users/prajwal.bhagat/go/src/phoenix/mainsvc/cmd/main/test.go:17 +0x1a
exit status 2
```

Comment: So in your `certmgr struct` you have `certToStore certtostore.CertStorage`  `certtostore.CertStorage` is an interface, you have to assign something to that. You're supposed to call `cert.certToStore = certtostore.OpenWinCertStore(...);` Since there's no documentation for ` certtostore.OpenWinCertStore(...)`  - I have no idea what the arguments you have to pass to ` certtostore.OpenWinCertStore()` means though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a library like [`google/certtostore`](https://github.com/google/certtostore), which is a multi-platform package that allows you to work with x509 certificates on Linux and the certificate store on Windows.

It does not fetch directly a certificate bundle, but does use the [Windows `certGetCertificateChain` call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certgetcertificatechain), which builds a certificate chain context starting from an end certificate and going back, if possible, to a [trusted root CA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secgloss/r-gly).

It is used by [`CertWithContext()`](https://github.com/google/certtostore/blob/f7827f50c8665309102a151fa09956532028dbda/certtostore_windows.go#L359-L366=), which performs a certificate lookup using value of issuers that was provided when `WinCertStore` was created.
It returns both the certificate and its Windows context, which can be used to perform other operations, such as looking up the private key with `CertKey()`.

---

> invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

You need to initialize the `var cert certmgr`

More generally, you need to get the store first, as in [this example](https://github.com/liupums/k6ncrypt/blob/150d520ec9f1bafc15ed3ea868a7c4eec4785f43/certstore/main.go):

```golang
    fmt.Println("open cert store")

    // Open the local cert store. Provider generally shouldn't matter, so use Software which is ubiquitous. See comments in getHostKey.
    store, err := certtostore.OpenWinCertStore(certtostore.ProviderMSSoftware, "", []string{"localhost"}, nil, false)
    
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("OpenWinCertStore: %v", err)
        return
    }   
    
    fmt.Println("get cert from cert store")
    // Obtain the first cert matching all of container/issuers/intermediates in the store.
    // This function is indifferent to the provider the store was opened with, as the store lists certs
    // from all providers.
    crt, context, err := store.CertWithContext()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("failed to get cert from cert store. ", err)
        return
    }
    
    if crt == nil {
        fmt.Println("no cert")
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("get key from cert")
    // Obtain the private key from the cert. This *should* work regardless of provider because
    // the key is directly linked to the certificate.
    key, err := store.CertKey(context)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("private key not found in %s, %s", store.ProvName, err)
        return
    }

    if key == nil {
        fmt.Println("no key")
        return
    }

    fmt.Printf("find cert '%s' with private key in container '%s', algo '%s'\n", crt.Subject, key.Container, key.AlgorithmGroup)
```

Comment: I have edited the question after using ` google/certtostore`, added the code

Comment: @PrajwalBhagat I have edited the answer for more visibility.